# Error while creating Workflow in WSO2 Identity Server(wso2is-km-5.9.0)

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I followed the steps mentioned in official WSO2 documentation https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adding-a-new-workflow-definition/ 
Steps to recreate the error:
1.Create local role (Approver) with permissions-Login Human Tasks > View Task List Workflow Management > BPS Profiles >View 
2.Created a workflow definition, added the above role(Approver) to this definition 
3.But when I try to create workflow engagement for this I get the following error.
[Workflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5XE8.png)
[Blank entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3a1A.png)

Also after this when I try to restart the server, it doesn't restarts.

Comment: Anyone having any clue on similar issue...please guide us for this

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue reported in the wso2 Github repository. Please refer to [this](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/6766)